# SQL Update Query From one Table to another

Tags: sql

I have a database which holds a set of traders and a set of contracts. There is a field on the trader table which I need to update from a field on the contract table. Can anyone help with a sample query?

Comment: What database are you using? Post the table schema.

Comment: @Rob The answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UPDATE from SELECT using SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

update trader

set trader.tofiled = contract.fromfield

from trader inner join contract on 
trader.id = contract.id

where  put the condition

Answer (score 0):

```
update trader join contract
on trader.id=contract.trader_id
set trader.field1=contract.field2
```

Answer (score 0):

Update trader
set t.tofield = c.fromfield
from trader t
join contract c on c.id = t.id
where t.id = 100
--make sure to select the row you want to update before you actually update to ensure you are updating the correct row.

select *
from trader t
join contract c on c.id = t.id
where t.id = 100